# i'm looking for a spacific function in numpy- python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Firs, I create a 2D array called temp_change representing the temperature change
during every hour of the 2 weeks. The shape of the array should be (14, 24),
where every row represents a day and the column number represents the hour
during the day, and I'm ussing the command np.random.normalto fill it.

after, I need to Create a new 2D array called temp_total with the same shape as
temp_change, which includes the total temperature at every hour.
For example,
temp_total[0, 0] = initial_temp + temp_change[0,0]
temp_total[0, 1] = temp_total[0, 0] + temp_change[0,1]

is there any way that I can do with numpy function, and without ussing two loops?
thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's called a "cumulative sum".  `np.cumsum` can do it.  Note that it only does one axis, so I suggest you reshape to one dimension first:

```
temp1 = initial_temp.reshape((336,1))
temp2 = np.cumsum(temp1)
temp_total = temp2.reshape((14,24))
```

You can do that all on one line.  I expanded it for easier debugging.  ;)

Note that, if you start over each day, so the deltas don't carry forward, then you don't need the reshapes.